# Is there a way to register new function to window object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to add a new function or can say register new function to chrome which can be globally accessible:-

But this should not get removed after refreshing the page and can be accessible in all tabs, even after refreshing?

Example
what exists like:-

1:- `window.fetch()` and can be used as `fetch(URL)`.

2:- `window.find()` and so on

what I want:-

```
window.customFunction
```

Can be used as

```
window.customFunction()
```

or

```
customFunction("some parameter")
```

Comment: You mixed up user-defined functions with APIs provided by the JS engine... What you want isn't possible.

Comment: Why do you want that? The initial requirements don't seem to be related with the end of your post. You can simply define `window.customFunction = function() {}` and you can already use it both as `window.customFunction()` and `customFunction()`. It won't persist across reloads but I'm not sure why that's a requirement - on reload of your page all your JS will run again which includes the `window.customFunction = function() {}` like so the function would be available again. Making it accessible in all tabs is a security nightmare, though - why do you want that?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that by writing a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide), probably one using a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that injects your function into the page. Users would have to install your extension to get access to the function.

Comment: I think there is another way to add a function that doesn't require addons or any work from the users. You just supply a new ECMAScript proposal, get it approved, and wait until the browsers support it. OK, I'm not saying it's *easy*.

Comment: @VLAZ - **LOL** Yeah, a [proposal](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) to TC39 or alternately to WHAT-WG for DOM and other browser API stuff. :-)